# Working in Full Motion Video (FMV), finalized multiplexed video not present?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, csv, arcgis-full-motion-video, misb-compliant

Working within Full Motion Video, I have a .mp4 video file and its corresponding .csv file (both from Contour 2+ camera). When video multiplexing, I am able to get a success message within ArcMap; supposedly resulting in a MISB compliant video.

But the finalized, multiplexed output video is not in the output location i selected into the Video Multiplexer! There is simply nothing there (no video file, metadata, etc.).

Does it save elsewhere, or is there a user error?

Answer (score 1):

I would review your CSV file.  If you have reopened it, the format will be lost for the Unix time stamp.  You have to format it as Number with zero decimal places before you save, ie, it can't be raised to some exponent.